# Sails.js stream keys and data to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js, node-streams

I have an angular frontend that populates data from a sails backend (using the sails-mysql adapter) into a ui-grid. This dataset is large and takes a while to load before the page appears to contain any data.

I have the basics of streaming from sails up and running:

```
findAllStream: function (req, res) {
    Model.stream().pipe(res);
}
```

So far this streams each individual piece of data from the model to the frontend. I'm using angular-oboe to consume this stream:

```
vm.myData = [];
var obj = {};
var count = 0;
Oboe({
    url: '/api/model/findAllStream',
    pattern: '*',
    start: function(stream) {
        // handle to the stream
        vm.stream = stream;
        vm.status = 'started';
    },
    done: function(parsedJSON) {
        vm.status = 'done';
    }
}).then(function() {
    // promise is resolved
    console.log('done');
}, function(error) {
    // handle errors
    console.log('error');
}, function(node) {
    // node received
    switch (count) {
        case 0:
            obj['id'] = node;
            break;
        case 1:
            regObj['property'] = node;
            break;
        case 2:
            regObj['function'] = node;
            break;
    }

    if (++count === 3) {
        vm.myData.push(regObj);
        count = 0;
        obj = {};
    }
});
```

Essentially, the nodes of data seem to come in the same order, so I just keep track of how many nodes I've received and build the object that way. I then push each object into an array for use in the uigrid.

For example, the data that would be returned by find() would be:

```
[
{
  id: 1,
  property: foo,
  function: bar
},
{
  id: 2,
  property: stuff,
  function: things
}
]
```

This works great with angular and uigrid. But with stream I would just get:

```
1
foo
bar
2
stuff
things
```

This is not ideal, especially if the model changes. Is there a way to send the key and not just the value? Or perhaps send JSON from the stream? Something like:

```
  id: 1,
  property: foo,
  function: bar
  id: 2,
  property: stuff,
  function: things
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was using Oboe incorrectly. I changed the match pattern to '{id}' and all was well.

```
Oboe({
    url: '/api/model/findAllStream',
    pattern: '{id}',
    start: function(stream) {
        // handle to the stream
        vm.stream = stream;
        vm.status = 'started';
    },
    done: function(parsedJSON) {
        vm.status = 'done';
    }
}).then(function() {
    // promise is resolved
    console.log('done');
}, function(error) {
    // handle errors
    console.log('error');
}, function(node) {
    // node received
    vm.gridOptions.data.push(node);
});
```